# how do i decrease opacity for every click

Tags: javascript, if-statement, dom, increment

i am  tryng to make an IF function for a value of opacity and then divide it by 10 to get a decimal in a range between `(0.9 to 0.0)`, the function works when there is no value `(!e.target.style.opacity)` and when opacityValue gets to `9`; but then it gets stucked in `8`, i want to trigger that event until opacity gets value to `0`;

```
function toEternalDarkness(e) {
    let opacityValue = 9;
    let opacityDegree; 
    if (!e.target.style.opacity) {     
        opacityDegree = opacityValue / 10;   
        e.target.style.opacity = opacityDegree;
        console.log(opacityValue);
    } else if (opacityValue > 0) {
        opacityValue--;
        opacityDegree = opacityValue / 10;
        console.log(opacityDegree);
        e.target.style.opacity = opacityDegree;        
    } else {return}
```

i tryed to declare the opacityDegree inside the iIF statement and it didnt work
i tryed to declare a new variable to store newOpacityValue and didnt work
i tryed a while loop inside the IF ELSE statement and it runs all the loop until opacity gets to zero;

here is a link for  the projects i am trying to solve:
https://github.com/AliQTank/Etch-a-Sketch/tree/Op002

a Grid created by multiple divs that change color with event listener mouseover, so i did my container background color black to decrease opacity level 10 percent for every event listener triggered and after 10 events, the color has to be totally transparent.
somebody put a solution applyed to a button, and didnt work in my project because if i triggered my opacity in one cell(div) the other ones get triggered from the last opacityValue, at the end one cell is triggreder from opacity 1 to 0.8 other from 1 to 0.7 and the last ones get from opacity 1 to opacity 0

Comment: Opacity is a value usually from `0` to `1`. Why do you forcefully try to use a system of max 10? Ehrm, 9?

Comment: Every single property on `.style` is a string. `e.target.style.opacity !== 0` will _always_ be true. Other than that, you set `let opacityValue = 9;` in your function. So the opacity value will always be 9. Put this declaration outside the function.

Comment: The logic of the code makes no sense. Is it supposed to cycle between fade-in and fade-out?

Comment: @Yogi it is grid with background dark with several divs that every time it gets clicked it has to fade out into a darker color until it gets 100% dark, each one has to have its own opacity level, has not to be affected by the other divs opacity

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, i read in similar questions that float numbers sometimes are tricky so i aded variable to divide it into 10, i didnt use the first value as a 10 because i supose a opacity = 1 ===  no attribute for opacity

Answer (score 1):

Dividing by 10 every time will make it go invisible really fast. Does this work for you?

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (!btn.style.opacity) btn.style.opacity = '1';
  opacity = parseFloat(btn.style.opacity);
  btn.style.opacity = opacity - 0.2;
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks. I've updated my answer to handle that. It makes the HTML a bit nicer too.

Comment: is it `increase` (see title) or `decrease` opacity? I'm lost...

Comment: @Mister Jojo it would be decrease

Comment: @MisterJojo The title says increase, but the question clearly implied decrease. Maybe an edit is in order.

Comment: @Alber_Quintana so, you have to edit and change your title...

Comment: @MichaelM. it didnt work out, i added the link for the project because i am not explaining myself very well, i appreciate your support and hope to make better questions in the future

Answer (score 1):

You can decrement the value within the division `opacityValue-- / 10` return the results of a conditional. Since you are using a number type variable to decrement the value by 10, there is no need to parseInt.

The snippit show cases a div with a white background and with each click the elements opacity style is decremented by the calculation => `opacityValue-- / 10`.

```js
let opacityValue = 9;

function toEternalDarkness(e) {
  return !e.target.style.opacity ? e.target.style.opacity = opacityValue-- / 10 : e.target.style.opacity = opacityValue-- / 10
}

document.querySelector('.cont').addEventListener('click', toEternalDarkness)
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cont {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  Click Anywhere To Reduce The Opacity Of This Element
</div>
```

EDIT: In the following snippit we use an object to track the click of elements laid out in a row on the page.

```js
let opacityValue = 9;

// empty obj to hold each element and its current opacity value
const sequence = {}

// use spread to turn elements into array
let sels = [...document.querySelectorAll('.selections')]

const toEternalDarkness = (e) => {
  // get the index of the event target within its nodelist using indexOf()
  // if the opacity value is greater than -1, then set the event targets opacity to
  // the value found in the array - 1 then divided by 10
  return sequence[sels.indexOf(e.target)].opacity > -1 ? e.target.style.opacity = sequence[sels.indexOf(e.target)].opacity--/ 10 : null  
}

// loop over array of elements
sels.map((sel, key) => {
  // map initial sequence array to starting opacityValue using key
  sequence[key] = { opacity: opacityValue }
  // add event listener to each element and call toEternalDarkness method
  sel.addEventListener('click', toEternalDarkness)
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.selections {
  height: 200px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="selections">
  1
</div>
<div class="selections">
  2
</div>
<div class="selections">
  3
</div>
<div class="selections">
  4
</div>
<div class="selections">
  5
</div>
<div class="selections">
  6
</div>
<div class="selections">
  7
</div>
<div class="selections">
  8
</div>
```

Comment: if i have ten different divs with the same class how do i decrease opacity for each without affecting the others? every one has to have its own opacity level, thats one reason i am having troubles declaring opacityValue outside Function

Comment: @Alber_Quintana I have added a snippit that uses an object to track the element being clicked and its current opacity, is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

```
let opacityIndex = 10;
let opacityValue;
var opacityDegree;

function toEternalDarkness(e) {
    opacityValue = opacityIndex -1;
    opacityDegree = opacityValue / 10;
    if (!e.target.style.opacity) {
        e.target.style.opacity = opacityDegree;      
    } else if (e.target.style.opacity !== 0) {
        e.target.style.opacity -= 0.1;
    } else {return}
}
```

this is the link to my github solution:
https://github.com/AliQTank/Etch-a-Sketch

and this is the preview:
https://codepen.io/AliQTank/pen/GRGNbJz